# Laravel 5.1 add Query strings in url

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

I've declared this route:

```
Route::get('category/{id}{query}{sortOrder}',['as'=>'sorting','uses'=>'CategoryController@searchByField'])->where(['id'=>'[0-9]+','query'=>'price|recent','sortOrder'=>'asc|desc']);
```

I want to get this in url: http://category/1?field=recent&order=desc
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query strings shouldn't be defined in your route as the query string isn't part of the URI.

To access the query string you should use the request object. `$request->query()` will return an array of all query parameters. You may also use it as such to return a single query param `$request->query('key')`

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function getAction(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
    {
        dd($request->query());
    }
}
```

You route would then be as such

```
Route::get('/category/{id}');
```

Edit for comments:

To generate a URL you may still use the URL generator within Laravel, just supply an array of the query params you wish to be generated with the URL.

```
url('route', ['query' => 'recent', 'order' => 'desc']);
```

Comment: Ok. So, how do i call this from my view?

Comment: Your options are to set variables in your controller and pass them into your view as normal (I would advise this as you can then validate them. Remember they're user input!). Or you can use the facade directly in your view `Request::query()`

Comment: The thing is that i was doing 
    `<a href={{url('route_url'}}></a>`
this. I guess now i can't do that.

Comment: You should still be able to do that, I've updated my answer with an example for generating URLs with query strings

Comment: Hmm almost figured this out. Now, only problem is that i already have a route declared `category/{id}','CategoryController@index'` and `{!! link_to_action('CategoryController@customQuery',null,['id'=>1,'query'=>'price','order'=>'desc]) !!}` goes to index method rather than going to customQuery method

Comment: The last part doesn't work in Laravel 5.3.Output is `http://localhost/route/recent/desc`

Answer (score 18):

if you have other parameters in url you can use;

```
request()->fullUrlWithQuery(["sort"=>"desc"])
```

Comment: GOLD answer! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('category/{id}/{query}/{sortOrder}', [
    'as' => 'sorting',
    'uses' => 'CategoryController@searchByField'
])->where([
    'id' => '[0-9]+',
    'query' => 'price|recent',
    'sortOrder' => 'asc|desc'
]);
```

And your url should looks like this: `http://category/1/recent/asc`. Also you need a proper [`.htaccess`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess) file in `public` directory. Without `.htaccess` file, your url should be look like `http://category/?q=1/recent/asc`. But I'm not sure about `$_GET` parameter (`?q=`).

Comment: You misunderstood my question. I get it what you're saying. But i want to do that with query strings.